# How to read unsigned values from files

Tags: java, unsigned

I am trying to read binary data (Doom WAD files), which contain a lot of unsigned short and unsigned byte values.

At the moment I read the file into a byte[], wrap a ByteBuffer with little-endian order around it and access the values by bbuf.getShort() etc. respectively.

Converting those e. g. to 2D-coordinates is not a problem, because in the end it won't matter if they range eg. from -128 to 128 or from 0 to 256, but more often the short values are used as array indices and short/byte values as flags/, so I need a fast way to treat them as signed types.
I know, Java doesn't have unsigned types "for sake of simplicity...".
Can you make any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In order to save unsigned `int`s you need a `long`. Then you need to truncate last 32 bits. You can use following trick to do it.

```
final long UNSIGNED_INT_BITS = 0xffffffffL;
int a = -3;
long b = UNSIGNED_INT_BITS & a;
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println(Long.toHexString(UNSIGNED_INT_BITS));
```

Output:

```
-3
4294967293
ffffffff
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, you could always store them internally as ints and make sure you do proper conversion when reading/writing.

(Read as byte/short, cast to int, add 2^bits if negative. Just truncate to 8/16 bits when writing.)

Hardly the most elegant solution, I admit.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to interprete 0xFF byte as 256 do the following

```
int n = b & 0xFF;
```